Keycloak 16 Quickstart Migration
I have a quickstart standalone keycloak v.16.1.1 working. This distribution has no database. Where are the data from users?
I need to migrate all data to a windows service deployment. I don't really know how to do it, even I don't find the data. Export / import doesn't seem to export users/passwords.
Any help will be appreciated.
